# Gcc compile pipeline: how to get abstract grammar tree?

Tags: gcc, compilation, tree, clang, grammar

I refered to gcc compile process and its like this, I have a f.c file:
The compile pipeline was like this:

```
cat f.c
#include<stdio.h>
void f(){printf("hello %d\n",1);}
```

I can manually compile this file in 4 steps:

```
1. cpp f.c f.i --> I get f.i file, all include and macros expanded.
2. gcc -S f.i  --> Compile this .i file, and get an assembly code file.
3. gcc -c f.s  --> compile into an .o file, this is in a standard format.
4. gcc f.o -o f--> Get executable.
```

So the process it, I get a very low level .s (assmebly) file first, then the object file format(platform independent?). I wish to know if .obj file is in a lower level then assembly described code?

My question:

i) Which step is called "code generation", step 2 to get f.s, or step 3 to get f.o?

ii) clang is built upon llvm, which provides an universal format for compiled grammar tree. If I use clang to compile my f.c, how to get a file containing compilation result of abstract grammar tree? Any command line options or configuration needed?

Comment: voting down without any comment is not very fair